# CLion how to set a breakpoint in exec'd process

Tags: gdb, fork, breakpoints, clion

I need to debug a complex program (SWUpdate) which spawns (actually fork()s) several sub-processes.

I can "follow" execution on child process using GDB commands:

```
(gdb) set detach-on-fork off
(gdb) set follow-fork-mode child
```

but I didn't find a way to set a breakpoint directly on a line which will be executed only in a child process.
Is there some way to set a breakpoint at a certain location *regardless* of executing thread/process?